# Facebook redirect_uri error, registration app. not loading

Tags: facebook, redirect, uri

I'm just putting some Facebook functionality on an existing website for comments and such and maybe a few other fun things later but, although all of the other functionality works, the log in button, the comments box and the like button the registration form just won't.

The error I'm getting is exactly as follows:

> Unable to load the registration form for
>   Roundhall_community_ecosystem. You may have previously blocked this
>   app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy settings to unblock this
>   app. (Error: Missing 'redirect_uri' query parameter.)

I'm not in sandbox mode and I followed the instructions on the developers' page and replaced the redirect_uri with the url of my site however given that this error is specified I still think this might be what is stopping the registration app. from loading.

The only other time the problem is recorded here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431870/using-facebook-registration-plug-in-iframe-and-getting-error-missing-redirec , the solution given is that a quotation mark is missing but the user doesn't say where.